# Form.Show not showing up in Taskbar in Vista

Tags: winforms

I have a winform app that is hiding it's UI and waiting on a named pipe message before showing up 
On receiving the event the thread invokes into the main UI thread and then does the following

Set the opacity to 100
ShowInTaskbar = true;
BringToFront();

ON Windows Vista the window does not show up on the taskbar though and the window is in the background . YOu cant say it 
if you finally find it and click on it, it shows up on the taskbar

any ideas on how to fix this

Comment: the answer you tagged is not working for me, what was the exact solution?

Comment: FlashWindowsEx worked for me 
I dont have access to that code now but that api worked 
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't work in vista but it might be better just to flash the taskbar or do a ballon popup or something like that. What your suggesting maybe a bit annoying to a user. Say there typing away and there looking at the keyboard and your window has stolen the focus they look back and find what they just wrote hasn't gone into the app they thought it was going into.[like this](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001011.html).

[flashing the task bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29460/stop-the-taskbar-flashing)

[this might help also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46030/c-force-form-focus)

Answer (score 1):

If the form has an Owner set it might or might not show up in the taskbar.

Don't set the Owner property and it should show fine (it did for me).